# "error: type mismatch" in Spark with same found and required datatypes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am using spark-shell for running my code. In my code, I have defined a function and I call that function with its parameters.

The problem is that I get the below error when I call the function.

```
error: type mismatch;

found   : org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph[VertexProperty(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC),String]

required: org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph[VertexProperty(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC),String]
```

What is the reason behind this error? Has it got anything to do with Graph datatype in Spark?

Code : This is the part of my code which involves the definition and call of the function "countpermissions".

```
class VertexProperty(val id:Long) extends Serializable
case class User(val userId:Long, val userCode:String, val Name:String, val Surname:String) extends VertexProperty(userId)
case class Entitlement(val entitlementId:Long, val name:String) extends VertexProperty(entitlementId)

def countpermissions(es:String, sg:Graph[VertexProperty,String]):Long = {
    return 0
}

val triplets = graph.triplets
val temp = triplets.map(t => t.attr)
val distinct_edge_string = temp.distinct    
var bcast_graph = sc.broadcast(graph)        
val edge_string_subgraph = distinct_edge_string.map(es => es -> bcast_graph.value.subgraph(epred = t => t.attr == es))
val temp1 = edge_string_subgraph.map(t => t._1 -> countpermissions(t._1, t._2))
```

The code runs without errors until the last line, where it gets the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the trick. Lets open the REPL and define a class:

```
scala> case class Foo(i: Int)
defined class Foo
```

and a simple function which operates on this class:

```
scala> def fooToInt(foo: Foo) = foo.i
fooToInt: (foo: Foo)Int
```

redefine the class:

```
scala> case class Foo(i: Int)
defined class Foo
```

and create an instance:

```
scala> val foo = Foo(1)
foo: Foo = Foo(1)
```

All whats left is to call `fooToInt`:

```
scala> fooToInt(foo)
<console>:34: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Foo(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)
 required: Foo(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)
          fooToInt(foo)
```

Does it look familiar? Yet another trick to get a better idea what is going on:

```
scala> case class Foo(i: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> val foo = Foo(1)
foo: Foo = Foo(1)

scala> case class Foo(i: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> def fooToInt(foo: Foo) = foo.i
<console>:31: error: reference to Foo is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import INSTANCE.Foo
and import INSTANCE.Foo
         def fooToInt(foo: Foo) = foo.i
```

So long story short this is an expected, although slightly confusing, behavior which arises from ambiguous definitions existing in the same scope.

Unless you want to periodically `:reset` REPL state you should keep track of entities you create and if types definitions change make sure that no ambiguous definitions persist (overwrite things if needed) before you proceed.

Comment: It's unclear from this answer how the original author should solve his problem.  This seems to only show how to create a similar error message using different code.

Comment: @GeorgeLewis Thanks for the feedback. Thing ism it is an expected behavior. Just the error message is not very clear. Other than keeping the state of REPL clean there and removing / overriding ambiguous definitions there is nothing to do here.

Comment: I think this was just a bug in how history was imported in the current line, where spark shell uses -Yrepl-class-based, and fixed in scala 2.11.9+.