# reduceByKey() function having case class as value failing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

```
case class employeeObj(fn:String, ln:String)
```

//don't worry too much about `processEmps` function as I am just returning first object to test functionality

```
def processEmps(m1:employeeObj, m2:employeeObj):employeeObj ={
  m1
}

var o1 = employeeObj("john", "king")
var o2 = employeeObj("john", "king")
var o3 = employeeObj("jason", "king")`

var x = sc.parallelize(Array(("a", o1), ("a", o2), ("b", o3)))
x.reduceByKey(processEmps)
```

When I call `x.reduceByKey(processEmps)`, it is failing by generating type mismatch error.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

[image]

Comment: What version of Apache Spark are you using? Have you tried to clean and recompile your whole code? Everything that you've posted works on Spark 1.6.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["error: type mismatch" in Spark with same found and required datatypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476790/error-type-mismatch-in-spark-with-same-found-and-required-datatypes)

Comment: @zero323 spot on! I am able to run this code without any errors. Getting the 'type mismatch' error after redefining the case class.

Comment: It works, when I use the following: var x = sc.parallelize(Array(("a",employeeObj("john", "king")), ("a", employeeObj("john", "king"))))
x.reduceByKey(processEmps)