# Why Scala Enumeration does not work in Apache Zeppelin but it works in maven

Tags: scala, apache-spark, enumeration, apache-zeppelin

Enumeration works as expected when I use it in a maven project(with the same Scala version).

```
object t {
  object DashStyle extends Enumeration {
    val Solid,ShortDash = Value
  }

  def f(style: DashStyle.Value) = println(style)

  def main(args: Array[String]) = f(DashStyle.Solid)
}
```

But when it runs in Apache Zeppelin(Zeppelin 0.6, Spark 1.6, Scala 2.10, Java 1.8)

```
object DashStyle extends Enumeration {
    val Solid,ShortDash = Value
}

def f(style: DashStyle.Value) = println(style)

f(DashStyle.Solid)
```

It reports the following error even it says found and required type is exactly the same

```
<console>:130: error: type mismatch;
 found   : DashStyle.Value
 required: DashStyle.Value
              f(DashStyle.Solid)
```

Why and how should I use it?

Comment: What is the Scala version your maven project?

Comment: On another note, I don't recommend using Scala Enumerations, they are notoriously buggy. I do recommend using ADTs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["error: type mismatch" in Spark with same found and required datatypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476790/error-type-mismatch-in-spark-with-same-found-and-required-datatypes)

Comment: @zero323, thanks. while my main question is why it works in maven but not in zeppelin(its the same in shell).

Comment: @pedrofurla, it's the same with one I used for zeppelin, it's 2.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the trick to solve this issue.

In Apache Zeppelin (or Scala REPL). In order to use Enumeration or sealed&object, it should be wrapped in object but not directly define on the root scope.

The reason why it works in maven is that I already put it into an object.

Define enumeration in an object in a Zeppelin paragraph

```
object t {
  object DashStyle extends Enumeration {
    val Solid,ShortDash = Value
  }

  def f(style: DashStyle.Value) = println(style)
}
```

Then use it in a Zeppelin paragraph

```
import t._
f(DashStyle.Solid)
```