# JSON Mapping with custom case class doesn't work in spark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, fasterxml

I want to do a json mapping with a scala case class like it is done here: https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/scala/BasicParseJsonWithJackson.scala

That works perfectly in "normal" Spark jobs that run on my cluster. But if I want to do that in a Zeppelin notebook or on Spark shell I get the following error:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class MyCaseClassName]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)`

Do you have any idea what the problem is and how I can fix it?

EDIT: I use the following versions:
Spark 2.0.2
Zeppelin 0.6.2
Scala 2.11
The Spark cluster and zeppelin runs on Google Container Engine (Kubernetes). But as I mentioned before, this problem also appears on a local Spark shell. So I think it's independent from Zeppelin version and Spark runtime environment.

Comment: Could you post env also? (e.g zeppelin, spark, OS versions)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot that. Please see edit of the original post.

Comment: It might be the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484154/why-scala-enumeration-does-not-work-in-apache-zeppelin-but-it-works-in-maven

Comment: I tried to wrap the case class in an "outer" object, import that in the next zeppelin paragraph and use the case class there, as @RockieYang suggested: Same error appears.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala#caveats

Maybe these class debug informations are diabeled in the scala interpreters in spark shell or zeppelin? But if that's the case, how do I turn that on?