# spark-shell "error: type mismatch" using :paste to define class/companion object

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Using spark-shell v1.6.

Big differences when I load a class def and its companion object depending on how it's done.

- one line at a time - OK
- via `:paste` - PROBLEM

First things first...  since the repl finds it ambiguous to load a companion object with the same name, I give it an altered name.  No problem there.  Setup lookes like this...

```
import scala.util.Try

class Foo5(val i: Int)

object Foo5Companion {
  def apply(i: Int): Foo5 = new Foo5(i)
  def apply(d: Double): Foo5 = new Foo5(d.toInt)
  def applyTry(i: Int): Try[Foo5] = Try { apply(i) }
  def applyTry(d: Double): Try[Foo5] = Try { apply(d) }
}
```

Now let's do something simple with this class.

```
val ls_i: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
val ls_foo: List[Foo5] = ls_i.map(Foo5Companion.apply)
```

If I've loaded the class def and companion object with `:paste` I get this error...  to be clear, Foo5 has only been defined once in  a new session.  This is not an instance of the issue described here:  ["error: type mismatch" in Spark with same found and required datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476790/error-type-mismatch-in-spark-with-same-found-and-required-datatypes)

```
<console>:42: error: type mismatch;
found   : List[Foo5]
required: List[Foo5]
        val ls_foo: List[Foo5] = ls_i.map(Foo5Companion.apply)
```

BUT...

if i load the same defs in line-by-line (without using `:paste`)...  it works fine...

```
ls_foo: List[Foo5] = List($iwC$$iwC$Foo5@66f1a93a, $iwC$$iwC$Foo5@39d53a3, $iwC$$iwC$Foo5@4dddf42f)
```

My question is...  what's the difference?  Why is `:paste` causing a problem and making the repl think `Foo5` is ambiguous?

Comment: I think it may be the same underlying issue as the linked question; the advice there to "keep track of everything in your head" is not friendly; that's the REPL's job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: this bug was [fixed in 2.11.9](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/86ae2f95ce33ef22f9c9ad40d6a966fbef7d352f#diff-2f1bceee7d6708ef28990867bc4e410d), so latest 2.11.12 works.

Edit: since you're on Spark 1.6, I supposed you're stuck on 2.10. That's OK, I just picked up Homer again the other day, and in a very old version (Lattimore, 1951).

It looks like an old bug with how the Spark shell is handling imports from history under `-Yrepl-class-based`.

With `-Xprint:typer`:

```
  import scala.util.Try;
  import $line3.$read.INSTANCE.$iw.$iw.Foo5;
  private[this] val $line3$read: $line3.$read = $line3.$read.INSTANCE;
  <stable> <accessor> def $line3$read: $line3.$read = $iw.this.$line3$read;
  import $iw.this.$line3$read.$iw.$iw.Foo5Companion;
```

One import is via an aliased member, so the paths to the two `Foo5` differ.

You can use `:load` instead of `:paste` in this case. Normally, you'd `:paste` companions.

This is no consolation, but it will be fixed when Spark upgrades to 2.12:

```
$ ~/scala-2.11.8/bin/scala -Yrepl-class-based 
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_171).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :paste foo5.scala
Pasting file foo5.scala...
import scala.util.Try
defined class Foo5
defined object Foo5Companion

scala> val ls_i: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
ls_i: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val ls_foo: List[Foo5] = List(1,2,3).map(Foo5Companion.apply)
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Foo5]
 required: List[Foo5]
       val ls_foo: List[Foo5] = List(1,2,3).map(Foo5Companion.apply)
                                               ^

scala> :quit
$ scala -Yrepl-class-based 

     ________ ___   / /  ___  
    / __/ __// _ | / /  / _ | 
  __\ \/ /__/ __ |/ /__/ __ | 
 /____/\___/_/ |_/____/_/ | | 
                          |/  version 2.12.6

scala> :paste foo5.scala
Pasting file foo5.scala...
import scala.util.Try
defined class Foo5
defined object Foo5Companion

scala> val ls_i: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
ls_i: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val ls_foo: List[Foo5] = List(1,2,3).map(Foo5Companion.apply)
ls_foo: List[Foo5] = List(Foo5@52354202, Foo5@6b1321b7, Foo5@342ee097)
```