# Import not found outside of class scope

Tags: scala, azure, apache-zeppelin, azure-hdinsight, scala-breeze

I'm running the Scala code below in a Zeppelin notebook, on an Azure HDInsight instance.

```
%livy2.spark

import breeze.linalg.DenseVector
var foo: DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector.zeros[Double](1)

class ClassBar() {
    var baz: DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector.zeros[Double](1,1)
}
```

The error I get is:

```
<console>:13: error: not found: type DenseVector
    var baz: DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector.zeros[Double](1,1)
                ^
<console>:13: error: not found: value DenseVector
    var baz: DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector.zeros[Double](1,1)
                                      ^
```

It works if I import DenseVector again inside the class definition but I don't understand why this is necessary? Shouldn't it find the DenseVector definition that is outside the class definition?

Comment: Perhaps duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/50495293/1296806 ? Yesterday I learned spark shell users deal with broken import generation. That particular bug improved in latest scala 2.11.11/12, but not 2.11.8 or 2.10 (for spark 1.6).

Comment: yes, this is bug of scala

Comment: Not sure what versions are involved here; another possible culprit is [SPARK-22393](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22393) fixed in Spark 2.3, back porting a fix for Scala bug [9881](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9881).